# Text Editor in eclipse plugin is not properly executed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, text-editor, undo-redo

I have created multipage HTML editor in which one tab has text editor. I have set the global action handler to the action bar for undo / redo actions in the source editor. Whenever I am adding something in the source editor then undo it, it is not returning the same code in the first attempt. It is completing in the second attempt. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

In the main editor override the setFocus() method and in this method call the following method of source editor.

```
public void setUndoRedoActionHandlers() {

    final IActionBars actionBars = getEditorSite().getActionBars();
    actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.UNDO.getId(),
            mUndoAction);
    actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.REDO.getId(),
            mRedoAction);
    actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.DELETE.getId(),
            mDeleteAction);
    actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(
            ITextEditorActionConstants.DELETE_LINE, mDeleteLineAction);

    actionBars.updateActionBars();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How can this be solved without even taking a look at the code??

Comment: Check the above source code.

Comment: If I remember correctly you should use a `MultiPageEditorActionBarContributor` as the editor action bar contributor class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you set global actions by overriding setFocus()? Look at this : https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_enable_global_actions_such_as_Cut,_Paste,_and_Print_in_my_editor%3F
It says they need to be set inside method setActiveEditor()

The reason I guess why you are seeing it working second time is - When the first time you click your editor gets focus and setFocus is called and only then the global actions are set. Then second time it will work because the actions are now set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I get the problem. It was due to the fact as delete action is already active on the source editor, so when I do the single delete operation from the designer then delete happens on the source editor as well as delete happens on the designer side, that again changes the source code. So two changes are happened on one click. And hence on undo the last source code is updated but the first delete on source code is not updated and hence the issue.

Comment: I have added the editorpart and text editor in the form editor. I want to add delete functionality on both the editorpart and source editor which will behave differently on both the editor. Can you tell me how can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: @ishan I cannot recollect correctly what exactly to do achieve what you are asking. Please look at [eclipse editor FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_get_started_with_creating_a_custom_text_editor%3F) I suppose you need to override setAction( DELETE )